# How to install on a laptop with no CD drive and no usb boot option

Tags: system-installation

I have an old 32-bit laptop with a broken DVD drive and the USB boot option doesn't work either. Its currently running Windows Vista.

How can I install Ubuntu on to it?

I know about WUBI but it seems to be dead (I can't find it anywhere).

Comment: Some of that looks relevant (e.g. doing a network boot), but I've discovered that 12.04 LTS has a working wubi.exe (http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe) and after installing via that you are invited to upgrade to 14.04, so that gets me to 14.04, not worked out how to get from there to 15.10 yet...

Comment: You need to upgrade step by step first to 14.10 (currently already outdated), then 15.04, then 15.10, if you really want to use 15.10. You can as well stay with 14.04 (LTS, supported until 2019) for another half a year, until in April 2016, 16.04 will come out, the next LTS. You can then directly upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS without the intermediate releases.

Comment: Going to 14.04 fell in a heap, had to revert to 12.04.
I'm very keen that Ubuntu should usurp Windoze so this kind of hiccup is annoying, switching from Windoze needs to be idiot proof from any context. I'm not quite an idiot and its hard.

Comment: Well, it's easy if you either have an USB drive or a DVD. How would you install Windows without that?

Comment: I have no working CD or USB boot capability, Windows was installed before the CD broke. Not economic to fix it. My hate of waste prohibits me junking the laptop, if nothing else its useful as an extra screen to something else. My motivation for swapping it to Ubuntu is my hatred of all things Microsoft and the better power characteristics of Linux - it keeps the fan quiet. Under Windows it sounds as if its about to take off!

This is getting off topic. Consider the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have an SD card slot? Thats how I did mine. Or if you get a USB DVD Drive it may show up in the boot menu.